# Inverse Hyperbolic function

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

For real no x it is fine that

$$\sinh^{-1}x=\ln\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)$$

But for complex number $z$ Since there is no order on complex numbers

Is it same and why?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how $\sinh^{-1}$ is found? Let's find out:

$$y=\sinh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2} ~\iff~ e^{2x}-2ye^x-1=0 ~\iff~ e^x=y\pm \sqrt{y^2+1}.$$

Now, if $x$ is real, then $e^x>0$, so $e^x$ cannot be $y-\sqrt{y^2+1}$ (as it's negative), forcing it to instead be $e^x=y+\sqrt{y^2+1}$ so that $x=\ln(y+\sqrt{y^2+1})$.

However if $x$ is not real, then both $x=\ln(y\pm\sqrt{y^2+1})$ are valid complex solutions to the equation $y=\sinh(x)$. Indeed, we haven't even addressed the fact that $e^x={\rm blah}$ has multiple complex solutions for $x$ because $e^{2\pi i}=1$.

To find a domain on which we can define an inverse, first we must pick a domain on which $\sqrt{y^2+1}$ is continuous and then restrict further to a domain on which $\ln(y+\sqrt{y^2+1})$ or $\ln(y-\sqrt{y^2+1})$ (whichever one we choose to use) is continuous for our choice of $\ln$.

Comment: And one more question in case of cosh^(-1)x = \ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}) here why donot we take -ve sign I:e cosh^(-1)=x\pm \sqrt{x^2+1}

Comment: @Milan Your comment is a bit confused. For real $x$, the function $\sinh(x)$ is bijective so it has an inverse, $\sinh^{-1}(y)=\ln(y+\sqrt{y^2+1})$. But $\cosh$ is not one-to-one on the reals - indeed it is an even function - so it has no inverse. The two solutions for $x$ to the equation $y=\cosh x$ are $x=\ln(y\pm\sqrt{y^2-1})$. (Except of course when $y=1$, where $x=0$ is the unique solution.)

Comment: I am asking why Cosh^(-1)x=\ln(x\+\sqrt{x^2-1}) and why not \ln(x\-\sqrt{x^2-1}

Comment: @Milan And I responded to your comment with a **complete explanation** of the situation. Please *read it until you understand it.* It's possible that you are reading some source - that you are not telling us about - which *chooses* $f(y)=\ln(y+\sqrt{y^2+1})$ as one of the two *right* inverses (meaning, it is a continuous function which satisfies $\cosh f(y)=y$), but it is not a bona fide inverse because $\cosh$ has no inverse. A similar situation happens with the square root function. The function $x^2$ (with domain $\Bbb R$) has no inverse, but $\sqrt{x}$ is a *right* inverse of it.

Answer (score 0):

In the complex plane, the function $z\mapsto \sinh z$ is not bijective, and therefore has no inverse.

Comment: ok that's good..it does mean that its true for real numbers since it is bijective over reals.

Comment: Yes but maybe we can restrict our domain like we do for sine and cosine on real numbers.

Comment: @MilanAmrutJoshi On reals, the inverse exists. I don't know if what you wrote is correct, I did not check.

Comment: What is not correct?

Comment: @MilanAmrutJoshi I did not say it is not correct. I said I did not check if it is correct.